# Precalculus Angle Vectors

Tags: vectors

Vector $\mathbf{u}$ has a magnitude of 4 and a direction angle of $30^{\circ}$. Write the component form of this vector. I don't understand where I need to even start at.

Comment: It's asking you to find the $x$ and $y$ components of the vector, using the standard $\mathbf{u}=(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))$ equation.

Comment: Draw a coordinate system with x and y axes.  If you draw a line from (0, 0) with length 4 and make angle 30 degrees with the positive x-axis, representing the vector, and draw a line from the "tip" perpendicular to the x-axis and then from the base of that perpendicular to (0, 0).  That gives a right triangle with angle 30 and hypotenuse 4.  The length of the "near side" is along the x-axis and has length 4 cos(30).  That is the x component of the vector.  Similarly, the length of the perpendicular to the x-axis is 4 sin(30).  That is the y component of the vector.

Comment: @AdrianKeister so my answer choices are     A.) u=(2,3.5 )   b.) u=(2.1,29.9)  c.) u=(3.5,2)   d.) u=(29.9,2.1)

Comment: @user247327  i posted the answer choices ^^^ do you think you know what it is

Comment: @Sheyanne Martinez: This is not a "we do your homework for you" website. You have three hints to follow up with: mine, user247327's, and math177618's. If you have additional questions about one of these approaches, feel free to ask, but we're not just going to hand you the answer, since that wouldn't help you understand at all.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a right triangle with hypoteneus of 4. We can write the vector with magnitude 4 at angle 30° as the sum of the vectors represented by legs of this triangle.  You want to find these vectors using right triangle trig.

Basically a the vector you are given has an x and a y component.  You have to find them using right triangle trig given that the hypoteneus is 4 and the angle is 30°